# Laravel: detect if nested relations are loaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

In Laravel we can load model with nested relations

```
User::with('posts.comments.likes')
```

But how in other place we can detect if nested relations are loaded? Is there a method?

Model::relationLoaded() detect only direct relation.

```
public function relationLoaded($key)
{
    return array_key_exists($key, $this->relations);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get the state of nested relations - at least no other way than iterating through related objects and checking relations individually for each of them.

Good reason why it's not implemented could be the fact, that if the relation is X-to-many, like in your case users can have multiple posts, it is possible to have comments eagerly loaded for only some of the posts in the collection.

Comment: Actually, it's not necessary to manually check relation loaded status, since this check is already present in `Model::getRelationValue()` when you access relation as a property: `$user->posts`